# How to auto create a new tab with existing link in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

How can I make this function run when I click on the extension icon or key "Shift+Ctrl+K"?

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'shift+ctrl+k', function replaceWeiboLink()
{
```

This content.js seems does not work.

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'shift+ctrl+k', function replaceWeiboLink()
{

        var url = document.location.href;

        if (url != undefined && url.indexOf("club.pchome.net/thread_1_15_")!=-1)
        { 
        url = url.replace("club.pchome.net/thread_1_15_","wap.kdslife.com/t/1/15/");
        url = url.replace("__.html","/?u=0&sc=235&rnd=0359251496");
        window.open(url);
        window.focus(); //send back the focus to the current window
                        } 
    window.setTimeout(replaceWeiboLink, 100);
});
```

Only the focus was on the new page, not opening tab as background. This string is not working, any idea?

```
window.focus(); //send back the focus to the current window
```

my manifest.json is

```
{
  "name": "linkmv",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "linkmv",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icon.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [ {
    "matches": ["http://*.club.pchome.net/*"], 
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "all_frames": true
  }]
}
```

This extension to do following, if the Chrome tab url match

```
http://club.pchome.net/thread_1_15_6865723__.html
```

it will open a new tab not active(in background) with the new url like following. The number 6865723 is different in different pages. Others are fixed.

```
http://wap.kdslife.com/t/1/15/6865723/?u=0&sc=235&rnd=0359251496
```

Original script come from (https://github.com/guiwuu/guiwuu/tree/master/chrome/linkmv)

Comment: What is the purpose of this script? Sounds a bit like browser hijacking.

Comment: The first page is HTML format for desktop, the second page is mobile format for the forum. I want auto convert the desktop html version to a url which can be read by mobile and send to my friend. That is.:-)

Answer (score 0):

Try window.open,

instead of:

```
document.location.href=document.location.href.replace(club.pchome.net/thread_1_15_,"wap.kdslife.com/t/1/15/");
```

try this:

```
var url =document.location.href.replace(club.pchome.net/thread_1_15_,"wap.kdslife.com/t/1/15/"; 
window.open(url);
window.focus(); //send back the focus to the current window
```

**NOTE: this might be overridden by a browser preference settings.**

Comment: Also try changing `if (href != undefined && href.indexOf("club.pchome.net/thread_1_15_^\d{7}$__.html")==-1)` to `if (href != undefined && href.indexOf("club.pchome.net/thread_1_15_")!=-1)`